# Module not found while running Docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker

My Dockerfile is written like

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# creates working directory
RUN mkdir -p /src
COPY ./drive-upload-python/ /src/drive-upload-python/
WORKDIR /src/drive-upload-python/

# installs dependencies
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/root/.local:/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages:/root/.local/bin:/root/src"
RUN echo $PYTHONPATH
ENTRYPOINT [ "python","drive_upload.py" ]
CMD [ "default-arg" ]
```

and my project structure is like

```
drive-upload-python
- creds
-- credentials.py
-- creds.json
- drive_upload.py
- other.py
- requirements.txt
```

My Requirements.txt

```
google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2
google-auth-oauthlib
psycopg2-binary
oauth2client
```

I am building the docker image with this command

```
sudo docker build --network=host -t drive-uploader . --progress=plain
```

and while running the docker image, I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/drive-upload-python/drive_upload.py", line 9, in <module>
    from creds.credentials import get_service
  File "/src/drive-upload-python/creds/credentials.py", line 6, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'
```

I have tried to

1. set the PYTHONPATH and PATH to /root/.local:/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages:/root/.local/bin:/root/src,  but it didn't work
2. login into interactive shell of docker via `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash drive-uploader` and tried to search for oauth2client with `pip show google-auth-oauthlib` which showed the path `/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` which was already into PATH and PYTHONPATH

Not sure, what else I can do. As far as I know, python imports search for modules at PYTHONPATH and PATH. Both are set, though still I am getting module not found error. Please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Since you are running as root when building the container, why not install the packages normally, with --user? Saves potential issues with PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I see `RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt`, but I don't see requirements.txt listed among the files in your project structure, nor anywhere else, nor do we see what requirements.txt actually contains.

Comment: I might argue you should `pip install` the packages _without_ `--user`; they'll be installed as part of the "system" Python, but in an isolated Docker images.  Don't touch `$PYTHONPATH`.